# pandas groupby will not do anything, including as_index if it detects the apply function doesn't do anything?

Tags: pandas, group-by

Pandas groupby will be 'smart' if it knows it doesn't need to do anything?

have a df

```
test = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 15}, {'a':1, 'b': 14}])
```

if we do

```
test.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1])
```

Then pandas will process everything,

```
a   b
a           
1   0   1   15
```

but if we just naively do nothing:

```
test.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x)
```

returns:

```
a   b
0   1   15
1   1   14
```

the return is the df itself - Normally we should expect the index would be changed to 'a', as the default value for 'as_index' is True. but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, pandas is "smart" in the way it processes the output, but not the way you think it is.

The decision to add the grouping keys depends on the **shape and index** of the output. Pandas doesn't detect what the function is doing to the values.

Let's use pandas 1.5.3 and just add 1:

```
test.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x+1)
```

We get a `FutureWarning`:

```
FutureWarning: Not prepending group keys to the result index of transform-like apply. In the future, the group keys will be included in the index, regardless of whether the applied function returns a like-indexed object.
To preserve the previous behavior, use

    >>> .groupby(..., group_keys=False)

To adopt the future behavior and silence this warning, use 

    >>> .groupby(..., group_keys=True)
  test.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x+1)
```

This clearly explains that **if the function keeps the index unchanged, then the grouping keys is not added to the index**.

If you want to have the key use an explicit:

```
test.groupby('a', group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: x+1)
```

Output:

```
     a   b
a         
1 0  2  16
  1  2  15
```